# Make up to get 2 object with native nativeQuery with MAX(ID)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table named Story:

```
sID |  sName  |  sView  
 1  |   s1    |    1  
 2  |   s2    |    11  
 3  |   s3    |    142 
 4  |   s4    |    152
```

Table Chapter:

```
 chID  |  sID  |  chName  |  chContent
   1   |   1   |    ch1   |    aaa  
   2   |   2   |    ch2   |    aaa  
   3   |   3   |    ch3   |    aaa  
   4   |   1   |    ch4   |    aaa  
   5   |   3   |    ch5   |    aaa  
   6   |   1   |    ch6   |    aaa  
   7   |   2   |    ch7   |    aaa
```

NaviteQuery:

```
SELECT s.*, MAX(c.chID) as chapterID FROM Story s 
       LEFT JOIN Chapter c ON s.sID = c.sID
       GROUP BY s.sID
```

Result:

```
 sID |  sName  |  sView  |  chapterID  
  1  |   s1    |    1    |      6
  2  |   s2    |    11   |      7
  3  |   s3    |    142  |      5
  4  |   s4    |    152  |     null
```

But you should get a 'SELECT s. *, c. * FROM ....', who can help me with !!!!

Comment: In your NativeQuery, `WHERE` should be `FROM`.

Comment: Exam : "SELECT s.*, c.* WHERE Story s  LEFT JOIN Chapter c ON s.sID = c.sID WHERE c.chID = (SELECT MAX(chID) FROM Chapter) GROUP BY s.sID".

Comment: result returned no sID = 4. While you need to sID = 4 to use. @Nick

Comment: I was just pointing out a typo... you have the same one in your comment, after `c.*` it should be `FROM`, not `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it on some differents way. For example you can use it:

```
SELECT s.*, c.* FROM Story s 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Chapter c INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(c.chID) as chapterID FROM Story s 
       LEFT JOIN Chapter c ON s.sID = c.sID
       GROUP BY s.sID) d ON c.chID = d.chapterID) c ON s.sID = c.sID
```

Comment: Thanks. But result returned no sID = 4. While you need to sID = 4 to use.

Comment: Try my new query

Comment: Query result good.  But must remove s.sID in "SELECT MAX (c.chID) ..." if no error duplicate